# datatables: sort only current pagination of table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatables](http://datatables.net/). And by default with pagination feature on sorting one column redraws all the table and puts you to the first page of paginated ones.
Is there an easy way to tell datatables that I want to sort and redraw only current pagination? And if there isn't how do I override default sorting feature?
Addition: I'm usin static data table without any ajax features.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437983/how-to-sort-only-the-current-page-using-jquery-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a few idea on the Internet but the only thing that worked for me was commenting out the reset to 0 in function _fnFilterComplete

```
/* Redraw the table */ 
/*oSettings._iDisplayStart = 0 Andrew nuked this 8/5/2013 ;*/
_fnCalculateEnd( oSettings );
_fnDraw( oSettings );
```

Comment: Your solution disables jumping around, but sorting still takes place over the whole dataset. My initial inquiry was to sort only rows that are currenty visible. Turned out there is no simple solution to this. This is the answer from datatables maintainer: [datatables forum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/50442). However this feature request was a glitch, no longer need it. Thanks for reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437983/how-to-sort-only-the-current-page-using-jquery-datatable